# getView() method displays only one ImageButton in the GridView

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am trying to use the GridView to create a set of Image buttons.
I am using an array list to store the images. Every time an image is assigned to a button through the getView() method, the images array list is reduced by one.

my problem is that only one button is shown in my grid! I am not sure if this is because the getView() method is called more than one time for each button. If so, I guess the array of images becomes empty before all buttons are assigned.

Any help is appreciated.
here is my code

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:layout_width= 'fill_parent'
android:layout_height= 'fill_parent'
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"    
/>
```

item_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Images as assigned randomly to the buttons and then removed from the list:
the assignImag()e method is in the MainActivity class and is called every time from the getView() method of the adapter class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList imgs = new ArrayList();
GridView gridView; 
.....
......
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
                      gridView.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
}


public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    ImageButton imageButton;


    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return imgs.size();
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         View gridView;
            if (convertView == null) {          
            gridView = new View(context);
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
                imageButton = (ImageButton) gridView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    // assign image to the button
        assignImage(imageButton);

                    } else {
                        gridView = (View) convertView;
                            }
        return gridView;
    }

} 
}

public void assignImage(ImageButton b){

    Random generator = new Random();
    int index = generator.nextInt(imgs.size());
    b.setContentDescription(imgs.get(index).toString());
    b.setBackgroundResource(imgs.get(index));
                imgs.remove(index);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried by removing imgs.remove(index); this line

Answer (score 0):

Modify your adapter like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4,
            -----
           R.drawable.imgN
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(67, 55));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

No need to create separate layout for each image in the gridView

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I need to use the random generator so that each time I can assign a different images to the buttons. Also, I need to use the ImageButton instead of the ImageView.

Comment: unfortunately I modified my code to use the above code but I am still getting a problem of why the assignImage() get's an error because the list goes empty very fast ...

Comment: Hi ABhi, sorry I missed your post. Yes, it works without that line (even before I ask the question). The problem is that I need that line of code because every image needs to be assgiend to only one button at a time and this has to be randomly!

Comment: Anybody figured out how to solve this puzzle? thanks in advance